# wxpython global name not defined error

Tags: wxpython

So, I am actually trying to restart a frame.  I have my frame defined in my mainF.py file, and my panels defined as classes in a panels.py file.  I call these two methods when my clear button is pressed:
self.frame.Destroy() 
main()

where main() is my method for jumpstarting my frame object.

In my mainF file, I am using this statement
from panels import * 
and in my panels file, I have tried
import mainF and
from panels import *

However, I always receive NameError: Panel1 is not defined.

This is confusing me since I do define it in my import statements, and the programs executes main() the first time through without this error.  When I had all classes defined in one file, I never received this error.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to circular imports.  One file is not yet fully imported when it imports another, which then imports the first one again.  Since it was already started the original module object is returned, but it hasn't yet defined the class you are looking for.